# how to achieve xxx.domainname.com  URL pattern?

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, web-applications

Consider the case of blogspot.com the domain is the one blogspot.com only but suppose i register in it with xxx then i will have xxx.blogspot.com like wise here it won't be the subdomain (i can smell) , but its some thing different ... how to achieve this ??
in j2ee web application..

Comment: Are you asking how to create sub domains using Java in your site? Something specific to BlogSpot? It's very hard to understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: nop i am not asking how to create sub domain..

but how to achieve this URL pattern..


there should be some another tweak...

i don't think that blogspot creates subdomain for each regustration..

got it ?

Comment: This is not programming related. This is serveradmin related. By the way, please put a bit more effort in your English in the question and the comments. You're writing like a little child in a chatroom, it does not encourage us to put effort in to post a professional answer.

Comment: One more question i have is suppose i buy a domain over internet, then how i can i achieve this configuration ? i have temporarily locally configured this DNS but what if i want each node in internet to resolve this pattern , how can this reflect all DNS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you need a DNS server that will resolve any subdomain as the adress of your server,
2. you j2ee application can optain the hostname from the request header

UPDATE: here is a example of a BIND zone file:

```
$ttl 38400
mauriceperry.ch.    IN  SOA ks31441.kimsufi.com. maurice.mauriceperry.org. (
            1237374933
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
mauriceperry.ch.    IN  NS  ks31441.kimsufi.com.
mauriceperry.ch.    IN  NS  ns.kimsufi.com.
*   IN  A   213.186.61.21
```

Here xxx.mauriceperry.ch will resolve to 213.186.61.21 whatever xxx is.

Comment: i don't think that blogspot creates subdomain for each regustration..

what say ?

there should be some another tweak...

Comment: well, if you are using BIND, you can use a wildcard * in an A record

Comment: btw what are these values...

1237374933
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 

?
will it remain same for my case?

Comment: No, they should be adapted. I don't remember what they all are, but the first is a sort of version number that needs to be updated each time the zone file is updated, so that the other DNS servers know when a refresh is needed.

Comment: Refering this link:http://ulyssesonline.com/2007/11/07/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-in-ubuntu/

/etc/bind/named.conf.local
# Our domain zone
zone "mydomain.com" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com.db";
};

# For reverse DNS
zone "200.1.192.in-addr.arpa" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.200.1.192.in-addr.arpa";
};

Comment: /etc/bind/named.conf.options
options {
 directory "/var/cache/bind";

 // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
 // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
 // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

 // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
 // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
 // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
 // the all-0's placeholder.

  forwarders {
  192.1.200.1
  };

 auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
 listen-on-v6 { any; };
};

Comment: /etc/bind/zones/mydomain.com.db
$TTL 3D
@ IN SOA ns.mydomain.com. admin.mydomain.com. (
   2007062001
   28800
   3600
   604800
   38400
);
mydomain.com.  IN      NS         ns.mydomain.com.
jigar  IN      A          192.168.0.29
www            IN      CNAME      jigar
gw             IN      A          192.168.0.29
                       TXT        "Network Gateway"
* IN  A   192.1.200.29

Comment: rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa
$TTL 3D
@       IN      SOA     ns.mydomain.com. admin.mydomain.com. (
                2007062001
                28800
                604800
                604800
                86400
)
        IN      NS      ns.mydomain.com.
29       IN      PTR     gw.mydomain.com.
29      IN      PTR     jigar.mydomain.com.

Comment: this is my configuration..
sorry to flood it like this, but got stuck here..

error i am getting..
 Stopping domain name service... bind9                                        rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused

Comment: You should have more information about the error in /var/log/messages

Answer (score 1):

1. Buy a domain name at you're favorite ISP.
2. Configure for this domain a [domain wildcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) for the A record in the [DNS zonefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file) (usualy using some nice tool from you're ISP):

   ```
   *   IN  A   74.125.77.191
   ```
3. Code a Java Servlet (or whatever you are using) as front controller. The front controller will dispatch you to what ever the subdomain needs to show.

   ```
   String domain = request.getLocalName();
   String subdomain = domain.substring(0, domain.indexOf('.'));
   goto(subdomain); // or what ever you need for the subdomain
   ```

Comment: Thankx...

can you help me what to do if i want to set up it in my local machine ?
its linux..
i have installed bind9
i don't know the configuration ..

Comment: Bind is not exactly an easy package to configure correctly. I would rather advice using dnsmasq. But why go through all the trouble if you can buy for $2 a domain name at godaddy.com that includes a free DNS server? If you just want to do a proof of concept, you can just edit the /etc/hosts file and add the needed (sub)domains. Although no wildcards are allowed in the hosts file, you can add as many domains as you like.

Comment: One more question i have is suppose i buy a domain over internet, then how i can i achieve this configuration ?
i have temporarily locally configured this DNS but what if i want each node in internet to resolve this pattern , how can this reflect all DNS ?

Comment: The easies way is to use the DNS server of you’re ISP and configure the A record via their web interface.